# How to convert seq2seq and attention model to .tflite format that can be deployed in Android Studio?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, seq2seq

I'm currently having an issue converting the model from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention) into a valid tflite model. I converted the saved model to tflite file with:

```
tf.saved_model.save(translator, 'test_translator', signatures={'serving_default': translator.tf_translate})

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('test_translator')
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops. 
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
] 
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]`
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

and successfully converted it, but when I insert it to Android Studio it will give me this error:

> This is not a valid tflite model file

[image: This is not a valid tflite model file]

The code and tflite file can be reproduced in this link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/197LS01TlMOBkPZWvnyJjl7WQFNrp4TK7?usp=sharing

Apart from this the tflite file's size nearly exceeds 200mb which is the maximum size that Android Studio can take.
My question is that is there a better way to convert a `seq2seq` attention model to Android Studio using Tensorflow 2.X (because I'm unfamiliar with Tensorflow 1.X) ?

Comment: Can you run the model outside android studio ? Basically we want to know whether it is an issue with android studio or with the tflite file generated.

Comment: @Karim Nosseir
 my model can run normally, I've attached a google colab link to reproduce this issue.